# Ajax response to load div problem, scripts and css not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart2.x

I'm loading content after an AJAX call success. It works fine and the content is passed to the page without reloading, but I'm stuck with a problem. It appears that some JS scripts are not working after the new content is placed. Is there a way of reloading all the JS scripts on AJAX response?

```js
// Slider 
$('.slider').each(function() {
  $("[id=" + this.id + "]").slider({
    range: true,
    min: parseInt($('[id=' + this.id + '] > #min ').val(), 10),
    max: parseInt($('[id=' + this.id + '] > #max ').val(), 10),
    values: [parseInt($('[id=' + this.id + '] > #min ').val(), 10), parseInt($('[id=' + this.id + '] > #max ').val(), 10)],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $('[id=' + this.id + '] > #amount ').val(+ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo curPageURL(); ?>',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
          min: ui.values[0],
          max: ui.values[1],
          Attr_id: $("[id=" + this.id + "]").data('id')
        },
        success: function(data, Attr_id) {
          $('#eot_filter_menu').html($('#eot_filter_menu', data).html());
          $('#content').html($('#content', data).html());
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

**EDIT 1:**
if i do the ajax call and aftwards I hit the refresh button the page refreshes correctly... That is why i think that there are scripts that are not loaded on div refresh

Comment: It apears that some scripts JS are not working after the new content is placed. Which JS scripts? Maybe events like 'click'?

Comment: Yes for example...

Even the .slider() is not working... it looks like all the events inside the <script> that has the ajax call is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

if the content load correctly then the problem is with other part of your page. you can reload in the success function the part that is not working. And if there are some of them you can put all in a function and call it.

Comment: i already did reload all the <head> in the "sucess" it did resolve a css problem that i was having with the request, but the JS still isn't working properly

Answer (score 0):

If you have listeners for example:

```
$('#eot_filter_menu #not_exist_yet_element_id').on('click', ...
```

it wouldn't work after content load dynamicly. You need to place listeners on higher DOM element.

Comment: some of the elements are inside that **eot_filter_menu** others are outside... and they both stopped working